# Display case information using Lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I want to display cases related to loggedin user account.
It is displaying empty list(it is not returning any values).
When tried in query editor the query is working I am not understanding where i am making mistake can anyone pls help me with this ?

here is my code:

Controller:

```
public class CaseInformation{

        @AuraEnabled
        public static List<Case> getCases() {

        ID contactId = [Select contactid from User where id =: Userinfo.getUserid()].contactId;
        if(contactId == null)
        {
            return NULL;            
        }
        ID AccID  = [Select AccountID from Contact where id =: contactid ].AccountId;
            if(AccID == null){
                return NULL;
            }
            System.debug('AccountId :' + AccID + 'ContactId:' + contactId);
            List<Account> allAssocaiatedAccounts = [Select Id, name, industry from Account where Id =: AccID];
            if(allAssocaiatedAccounts.size() != 0){
            return [Select CaseNumber,Status,Priority,Type,Subject,AccountID from Case where AccountID IN: allAssocaiatedAccounts];
            }
            else {
                return NULL;
            }
    }  

}
```

Lightning component:

```
<aura:component controller="CaseInformation">
<aura:attribute name="caseRows" type="Object[]"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:iteration var="cas" items="{!v.caseRows.Cases}">
                    <tr class="border_bottom">
                        <td > {!cas.CaseNumber} </td>
                        <td > {!cas.Subject}  </td>
                        <td >{!cas.Status}</td>
                        <td> <ui:outputDate format="MMM dd yyyy" value="{!cas.CreatedDate}"/> </td>
                        <td >{!cas.Account.Name}</td>
                    </tr><hr class="hrcolclass" />
                </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

component controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper){
        helper.getAllCases(component);
     }
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    getAllCases : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getCases");

        action.setCallback(this, function(a){
            component.set("v.caseRows", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a customer/partner community? Can you please verify that the value of `allAssociatedAccounts` is not null by using System.debug() statements?

Comment: Yes I am using for partner communities I debugged case list